# GeoXML undefined error after porting Google Maps to V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am in the process of porting over a script to V3 I have that a friend of mine wrote years ago but I am getting this in the error console...

> Error: GGeoXml is not defined

This worked fine with V2. Is this no longer acceptable to use in V3 and if not what are my solutions.

Here is a snippet from the code that is relative.

```
var map;
    var geoXml;
    var lcolor = 'white';                       //This defines the line color for the target circle
    function initialize() {
         {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            geoXml = new GGeoXml(URLToKML + "?rand="+(new Date()).valueOf() );

            map.setCenter(llCenter, 5);
//          map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
//          map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());   // smaller map control
//          map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

            // Comment these listeners out if you don't want "hiding" controls
            map.hideControls();
            GEvent.addListener(map, "mouseover", function(){
                map.showControls();         //'mouseover' listener shows controls
            });
            GEvent.addListener(map, "mouseout", function(){
                map.hideControls();         //'mouseout' listener hides controls
            });

            map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
            map.setMapType(G_HYBRID_MAP);        // Use one of these three as your initial map
//          map.setMapType(G_SATELLITE_MAP);
//          map.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP);
            map.addOverlay(geoXml);
```

Here is the link to the full js code that I am using for the map if anyone would like to see the complete code. I may have missed something in porting it to V3

[DEMO CODE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/lightning.js)

**EDIT:** Ok I have the map showing but I am not sure if I have the KML set up correctly. I am trying to insert a variable because the KML file is created dynamically from other script as the data changes every 30 seconds and suppose to refresh the page. I can get it to read the KML file like this if I call it directly....

```
var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.mesquiteweather.net/NSGMap/GMStrikes.kml',
                  {
                      suppressInfoWindows: false,
                      map: map,
                      preserveViewport: true
                  });

}
```

But when I try to call it dynamically with the variables that is defined above the code it doesn't read it. This worked fine in V2.

```
var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('URLToKML + "?rand="+(new Date()).valueOf()',
                  {
                      suppressInfoWindows: false,
                      map: map,
                      preserveViewport: true
                  });

}
```

Here is a link to the code I am using for this map.

[UPDATED DEMO CODE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/demo.js)

Here is a link of how it's suppose to work using V2.

[EXAMPLE V2](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/NSGMap/NSGMap.php)

Here is the link to the V3 version which I am having problems with converting.

[V3 EXAMPLE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxgmap_lightning.php)

What am I overlooking that is causing this to not read this properly in V3 like it did in V2?

-Thanks

Comment: GGeoXml is the Google Maps API KML parser.  The equivalent in the v3 API is [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)

Comment: @geocodezip I have added an edit to the end of my Original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors in the javascript console in Chrome:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.mesquiteweather.net/elabel2.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerWithLabel is not defined   wxgmap_lightning.php:732
```

Update:
I still get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ELabel is not defined wxgmap_lightning.php:733
```

I have a ported version of Mike Williams' elabel to v3 somewhere.

No guarentees (not sure where it came from or how well tested it is):
[v3 elabel](http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_elabel.js)

If URLToKML is a variable, you want to remove the ' that surround it.

```
   var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('URLToKML + "?rand="+(new Date()).valueOf()',
              {
                  suppressInfoWindows: false,
                  map: map,
                  preserveViewport: true
              });

    }
```

Should be

```
  var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(URLToKML + "?rand="+(new Date()).valueOf(),
              {
                  suppressInfoWindows: false,
                  map: map,
                  preserveViewport: true
              });

  }
```

Comment: The elabel2.js should be there now. It shouldn't be looking for it in the root anyways but it's there now. The MarkerWithLabel is something I am trying to sort out now as that was GSize which is depreciated in V3. I updated my OP with an issue that I think is causing the problems as it needs to be formatted a certain way which worked in V2 otherwise it won't update the KML which I posted a working example of it on V2.

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting that ELabel is not defined error. I have been all through the code which is not much and I am not sure what I am over looking. I have a copy of the Elabel.js and it is there [ELABEL.JS](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/elabel2.js) I am sure that is what is causing my issues. The KML issue is resolved but the page is working like it should which I think is because of the error I am getting. I had removed the ' ' from that originally but didn't see the results I was expecting so I thought I had it wrong.